# Conjugate prior for parameter W when the likelihood is normal with mean and variance both functions of W

Tags: probability, bayesian, prior, conjugate-prior

Suppose that $x$ is an observable scalar variable and
$$
 x \thicksim N(W\mu_0,W^2\sigma_0^2)
$$
Where $W$ is a parameter that must be estimated from data, and $\mu_0$ , $\sigma_0$ are known constants.

I want to solve the problem in Bayesian framework, so I consider $W$ as a random variable, and I have to choose a prior probability distribution for it.

What is a suitable conjugate prior for W in my problem? (I prefer the priors which belong to a known family of distributions).

Comment: Could you give some information about what you are trying to model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural conjugate prior for this model is 
$$ p(W) \propto W^{-a}\exp\left(-\frac{b}{W^2}+\frac{c}{W}\right)$$
and its posterior is 
$$ p(W|x) \propto W^{-(a+1)}\exp\left(-\frac{(b+x^2/[2\sigma_0^2])}{W^2}+\frac{(c+x\mu_0/\sigma_0^2)}{W}\right).$$
It is not from a family of distributions that I know and I have no idea if, or for what parameter settings and data, this will be valid probability density.

This problem is related to the [generalized inverse Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution#Conjugate_prior_for_Gaussian) which is the conjugate prior for the model 
$$ x|W \sim N(\alpha+\beta W,W) $$
the difference is that $W$ shows up in both the mean and the variance rather than $W^2$ in the variance.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I need to draw a sample from this distribution in my C++ program. Can you suggest an efficient method?